# How to ignore NaN's in a columnwise size query for a [n x 1] matrix (in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, size, cell, nan

I have a cell in Matlab: `c [3x1 double]`, with the values:

```
c{1}(1) = 0.4980
c{1}(2) = NaN
c{1}(3) = NaN
```

Now I want to know the (columnwise) size of cell `c`, when ignoring any NaN's (which would be `size = 1`). Normally i would use:

```
size(c{1},1)
```

But this doesn't ignore the NaN's (and thus returns a `size = 3`). Does anyone know how i could calculate the size of this cell compensating for any NaN's (as efficiently as possible)?

Comment: I doubt there's any option but to loop and determine which entries are NaN.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, That's what i was afraid of.. This is just an example cell (to simplify the question). The actual cells i'm using are a bit bigger, so it's going to take a lot of time. Ah well :)

Comment: maybe you would like it to respond size=3 but it responds size=1, just correct `size(c{1},1)` to `size(c{1},2)`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, writing a for, I would expect no less...

Comment: @g24l: Yes, your answer works for the OP's specific example.  But I doubt there's a "clean" solution to the actual question in the title (which doesn't correspond to the example!).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth , the actual title is an ill-posed problem. Suppose, I have two rows with 4 and 7 NaNs respectively, how will I determine the size? is the OP asking to find out the number of elements?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using cells? Why not use a matrix? Judging by your comments you want to look into using a sparse-matrix. In this way you only enter the values that are not null/zero. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f6-8856.html

Also I know of no way to ignore NaNs in size calculations. They tend to be ignored in min/max calculations.

Comment: I don't want to use cells, but it's what `[m,f,c] = mode(B)` returns, so i'm pretty much stuck with it. Unless i convert it to a matrix, but that's a little too inefficient, alas.

Comment: Is it really too inefficient with something like cell2mat? In my work I have found it carrier little penalty.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = find(isnan(c{1}(1)))
length(a)
```